# Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate() in php 5.512 usando wampserver 2.5

Tags: php, wamp, sqlite3

Estou estudando SQLITE3 e PHP e verificando um exemplo do Manual PHP apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate()
```

Exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.sqlite3.php

Instalei o PEAR no Wamp mas o erro continua aparecendo.

As extensões Intl e sqlit3 estão habilitadas no php.ini

Obrigado.

Comment: Esse erro não nada com sqllite.

Comment: Já olhou se essas dlls estão na pasta  ext?

Comment: Olhei e estão na pasta ext as DLLs cheguei até substituir por outras de versões diferentes do PHP mas não funcionaram, pois o PHP dava erro.

Answer (score 1):

O método `transliterator_transliterate()` pertence a classe [Transliterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/class.transliterator.php), que faz parte da extensão [intl](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/book.intl.php). Para habilita-la, abra o php.ini, procure pela linha, remova o `;` e reinicie o apache.

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Para extensão do sqllite3, descomente essa linha

```
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

Comment: A extensão php_intl e php_sqlite3 já estavam habilitadas e o erro permanece.